# Add a Join to this LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, linq

So after what felt like a lot of head banging, I have this query:

```
var widgets = db.Updates
      .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
      .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)       
  .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First()).ToList();
   widgetGrid.DataSource = widgets;
   widgetGrid.DataBind();
```

Now that I have all the sold widgets I need to add a join, let's say for instance that I want to join the the "Owner" table on ID in Owner equals ID in Widgets and then select Owner.Name and Widget.Style

For the life of me, I seem to be getting nowhere fast... anyone?

As always... I'm deeply grateful for anyone's time in helping me clear out my cobwebs.

Comment: is this EntityFramework? Also, show us the definitions of the tables. if this is EntityFramework, in your DbSet you should have set up a List in Owners for Widgets, and you would just have db.Owners.Include(x => x.Updates).//Get the stuff you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have two sequences:

- a sequence of Widgets, where each widget has a property Id.
- You have a sequence of Owners, where each owner has a property Id

And you want the combination of sequences and owners that have a matching Id.

By the way, probably your widget will have an ownerId or your owner will have a widgetId, but that won't influence the solution.

The join will be as follows:

```
var joinedTable = widgets.join(owners,  // join table widgets with table owners
    w => w.Id                 // from widgets take the Id
    o => o.Id                 // from owners also take the Id
    (widget, owner) => new    // where those Ids match, take the owner and the widget
    {                         // and take the properties you want
        Id = widget.Id,
        MyXProperty = owner.X,
        MyYProperty = widget.Y,

        Widget = widget,      // or take the complete widget and owner
        Owner = owner,
    });
```

By the way, you write "Now that I have all the sold widgets". From your piece of code I understand that each Update has a Boolean property Sold and that you want all Updates where !Sold. I'd assume you end up with items that are not sold?

What is the advantage of your predicate in the where clause. Why isn't it:

```
var widgets = db.Updates.Where(c => !c.Sold)
    .GroupBy // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var widgets = db.Updates
      .Where(c => !c.Sold)
      .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)       
      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault());

var result= (from w in widgets
             join o in db.Owners on w.OwnerId equals o.Id
             select new {o.Name, w.Style}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks very very much to everyone who was kind enough to take the time to help me!  I believe that all the answers would work, some of the syntax made more sense to me and there may be performance differences but either way, I'm very grateful to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

you may also try:

```
var widgets = db.Updates
      .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
      .GroupBy(c => c.widgetType)       
      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First())
      .Join( db.Owners,
             u => u.ID,
             o => o.ID,
             (u, o) => new { o.Name, u.Style }).ToList();
```